# To have AR support back after creating project with --skip-active-record option in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a Rails 3 project with mentioned option. Can I somehow "revert" this option and have active record back as in default, or must I create a new project?

---

EDIT

Ok, to have ActiveRecord support back I had to:

1. Delete separate require calls in `application.rb` and replace it with `require 'rails/all'` (or just uncomment `# require "active_record/railtie"`)
2. Uncomment `# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'` line in Gemfile (for sqlite)
3. Create database.yml file and fill it with options
4. invoke `rake db:create` task

After that it seems that I can continue to work with AR as usual.

Comment: The accepted answer is good for any version of rails.  The section that you added is known to work for Rails 3, but looks like it might also work for rails 4.  What do you think about removing your edit and adding it back as a an answer, noting in the answer that it was testing and found working with rails 3?  After that, I think we can change the title and tags of the question to not refer to rails 3 specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a new project with ActiveRecord, and then pairwise diff `config/application.rb` and `config/environments/*.rb` to determine if there are any default settings you should add back to your project.