# How to enable ActiveRecord on skip-active-record rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have just created a rails apps with `skip-active-record` for the first time, but after a few months, I need to store to the database. How do I enable ActiveRecord in my current application?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338578/to-have-ar-support-back-after-creating-project-with-skip-active-record-option

Comment: Based on your link, i've just create another application without skip-active-record and search for active_record and ActiveRecord, and compare with my old skipped activerecord application.